# Proving that $\mathbb{R}$ is a field

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, definition, real-numbers, rational-numbers

Assuming that we have the definition of the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ we define $\mathbb{R}$ as the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ with respect to the usual norm. I want to understand why this gives a field.

By definition of the construction, $\mathbb{R}$ is defined as equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences $\{x_n\}$ with $x_n\in \mathbb{Q}$. That is
$$
\mathbb{R} = \{[\{x_n\}] : \{x_n\}\text{ Cauchy in } \mathbb{Q}\}.
$$
Here $\{x_n\} \sim \{y_n\}$ if $\lim_{n\to \infty} \lvert x_n - y_y\rvert = 0$.

I believe the operations on $\mathbb{R}$ are
$$
[\{x_n\}] + [\{y_n\}] = [\{x_n + y_n\}] \\
[\{x_n\}] [\{y_n\}] = [\{x_ny_n\}] 
$$

I believe I have shown that $\mathbb{R}$ is a commutative ring. All I have left to show is that all the (non-zero) elements have multiplicative inverses.

But if I have $[\{x_n\}]\neq 0$, then I can just define $y_n = 1/ x_n$ so that
$$
[\{x_n\}] [\{y_n\}] = [\{x_n y_n\}]  = [\{1\}]
$$

I am under the impression that the inverse part of the proof is hard, so I am guessing that there is something wrong with my approach.

**Am I doing the right thing?**

Comment: Note that $[\{x_n\}]\neq0$ does not imply $x_n\neq0$ for all $n$, so you can't define $y_n=1/x_n$ that easily. However, you have $x_n\neq0$ for all *sufficiently large* $n$, so that can be fixed.

Comment: For a given $\{x_n\}\in[\{x_n\}]$, there exists $N$ such that $x_n\ne 0$ for $n\geqslant N$. So define $y_n = 0$ for $n<N$ and $y_n = 1/x_n$ for $n\geqslant N$. Something like that, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see what's the meaning of $[\{x_n\}]\ne0$. Since $0$ is the equivalence class of the constant zero sequence, we know that it doesn't hold
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}|x_n|=0
$$
Thus there exists $\eta>0$ (rational) such that, for every $n$, there is $m>n$ with $|x_m|\ge2\eta$.

On the other hand, $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy, so there exists $\bar{n}$ such that, for $m,n>\bar{n}$, $|x_n-x_m|<\eta$.

Fix $m>\bar{n}$ such that $|x_m|\ge\eta$; then, for every $n\ge\bar{n}$,
$$
x_m-\eta<x_n<x_m+\eta
$$
If $x_m>0$, then $x_m\ge2\eta$, so $x_n>\eta$; if $x_m<0$, then $x_m<-2\eta$ and so $x_n<-\eta$.

In either case we can state that $x_n\ne0$, for every $n>\bar{n}$.

Define a new sequence $\{y_n\}$ by $y_n=0$ if $0\le n\le\bar{n}$ and $y_n=x_n^{-1}$ if $n>\bar{n}$.

Now the task is to prove that $\{y_n\}$ is Cauchy. Once you have this, you can easily prove that $[\{x_n\}][\{y_n\}]=1$ (the equivalence class of the constant one sequence).

You need to use that $|x_n|\ge\eta$ for every $n>\bar{n}$.